# Call a Fragment from Activity on back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a viewpager, and I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter. Now, the tab 0 of the FragmentPagerAdapter has an option that takes the user to a fragment, call it fragment B --It replaces the fragment of tab 0 with Fragment B, within the viewpager itslef. This Fragment B has an option that opens up an activity, now when I press back when in the activity, I'd like to go back to tab 0, rather than Fragment B. How do I achieve that?

Tab 0's fragment calling Fragment B:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                TagFrag f = new TagFrag();

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.note_container, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
```

Comment: @OneWay, that just takes me back to Fragment B again, but now, when I press back in Fragment B, it doesn't take me back to tab 0's fragment. That's not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2:**

[This Repo](https://github.com/rnrneverdies/PopFragmentOnBackPressed) demonstrates this answer with a concrete example (for Android Studio 1.0.1)

**UPDATE 1: <sup>*NOTE ANSWER EDITED:*</sup>** *`onActivityResult` should be placed on `FragmentB` instead of `FirstActivity`*

In ***FragmentTab0***, add FragmentB ilike this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.note_container, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

In ***FragmentB***, Open the second activity using `startActivityForResult`

```
Intent intent = new Intent((FirstActivity)getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1234); // 1234 is the RequestCode
```

In ***SecondActivity***, override `onBackPressed`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
      setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
      super.onBackPressed();
}
```

In ***FragmentB*** override `onActivityResult` and call [`getFragmentManager().popBackStack()`][2]

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1234) { // previously defined request code
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // magic happens here.
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! I actually just made the Fragment B into activity, after  I realized spending a lot of time on a problem I wasn't getting the answer to. I'll just upvote your answer for now, since I cannot try it. If it gets positive responses, or if someone can verify, I'll mark it correct.